# How to get the first word before a separator in PHP

Tags: php

So Basically I have a string like this:

```
kbIr cugY icqwrY BI; cugY cuig cuig icqwry ]
```

What can I do so PHP takes part of the string before `;` and then gets the first word before the separator so the output would be:

```
BI
```

So far I have: `strtok($g, ';');`, but that only gets the first half of the string before the separator, not the first word before the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be complete and if you don't like regex:

```
$value = end(explode(" ", array_shift(explode(";", "kbIr cugY icqwrY BI; cugY cuig cuig icqwry ]"))));

print_r($value); // prints BI
```

Answer (score 3):

This regex pattern matches upper and lowercased letters (with no space) followed by a semicolon. I've also added a named group for the capture.

```
(?P<sep>[a-zA-Z]*);
```

Example use

```
$re = '/(?P<sep>[a-zA-Z]*);/';
$str = 'kbIr cugY icqwrY BI; cugY cuig cuig icqwry ]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BI;
        )

    [sep] => Array
        (
            [0] => BI
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BI
        )
)
```

Simplified

```
if (isset($matches['sep']) and len($matches['sep']) > 0) {
    echo $matches['sep'][0]; // BI
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get *only the first word before the separator* it's enough to use `preg_match` function:

```
$str = 'kbIr cugY icqwrY BI; cugY cuig cuig icqwry ]';
preg_match("/\b\w+(?=;)/i", $str, $m);

print_r($m[0]);
```

The output:

```
BI
```